# Can I still migrate firebase cloud functions to Node.js 10 after Feb 15 2021?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

> Node.js 8 has been deprecated.
>
> - Starting Feb 15, 2021, we’ll no longer support new deploys or updates of Node.js 8 functions.
> - Starting Mar 15, 2021, we’ll no longer support executions of existing Node.js 8 functions.

I totally forgot about the deadline for deploying and updating Node.js 8 functions to Node.js 10.

Now (Mar 2 2021) it has been two weeks since the deadline for updating, but is there still any way for me do edit the node.js version of my cloud functions ?

Or will I have to delete all of them from the console and deploy them again using Node.js 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since February 15 it is no longer possible to **deploy** Cloud Functions that use the Node.js 8 runtime.

Once you upgrade the code to a newer Node version and select that newer runtime in the configuration, you can deploy them again. There is no deadline by which you must perform this upgrade.